# Array out of bounds exception? (Working on conway's game of life)

Tags: java, arrays, conways-game-of-life

So I'm about halfway through my first java class... so you might need to break it into baby steps for me, I apologize!

I'm working on Conway's game of life right now. Luckily we are not using a gui for it (...yet?) but I'm still stuck on simply setting up the grid. 
My code is compiling fine, but when I run I get:
Error: Could not find or load main class gameOfLife
So, I looked into it more and it seems that the issue is with my grid file, which gives the same error:
Error: Could not find or load main class Grid

EDIT**: this is how I am running them

```
[bgorgero@sraysvcs2 gameOfLife]$ java gameOfLife
Error: Could not find or load main class gameOfLife
[bgorgero@sraysvcs2 gameOfLife]$ java Grid
Error: Could not find or load main class Grid
```

EDIT*:

```
[bgorgero@sraysvcs2 ~]$ java gameOfLife/gameOfLife
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at gameOfLife.gameOfLife.main(gameOfLife.java:20)
```

That is the error I get when I try to access it without being in the folder.

I'm trying to get the grid to read from the input txt file to find out how large the array should be, and then read the 0's and 1's and store them into the array. So far, this is my code

gameOfLife.java

```
package gameOfLife;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class gameOfLife{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
       File input = new File("gameBoardInput.txt");
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(input);
        int x = reader.nextInt();
        int y = reader.nextInt();

        Grid grid = new Grid(x,y);

        for(int i = 0; i < x; i++){
            String cupcake = reader.nextLine();
            char[] muffin = cupcake.toCharArray();
            for(int j = 0; j < y; j++){
                grid.setAt(i,j,muffin[j]);
                }
            }

    }
}
```

Grid.java

```
package gameOfLife;
public class Grid{
    protected int[][] grid;

        public Grid (int x, int y){
           grid = new int[x][y];
            for (int i = 0; i < x; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < y; j++){
                grid[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

        public int nuggets (int x, int y){
        return grid[x][y];
        }

        public void setAt(int column, int row, int alive){
        grid[column][row] = alive;
        }


}
```

my gameBoardInput.txt is simply:

```
5
6
01000
00100
00010
01110
00100
00000
```

Thank you guys!

Comment: What are you typing at the command line to run the program?

Comment: Can you please post the stack trace of the Exception you are getting?  Your title implies an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, but in your question you talk about a "class not found" error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your class is in `package gameOfLife;` You need to have the class in a directory called `gameOfLife`

Then, run it with:

```
$ java gameOfLife/gameOfLife
```

Make sure that, based on the code you provided, the `gameBoardInput.txt` is in the same directory. I got it to run with a different error on my computer:

```
$ ls . gameOfLife/
.:
gameBoardInput.txt  gameOfLife

gameOfLife/:
gameOfLife.class  Grid.class

$ java gameOfLife/gameOfLife
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
        at gameOfLife.gameOfLife.main(gameOfLife.java:20)
```

---

As an aside, you should never name classes with a lowercase letter. I recommend `GameOfLife` for the class instead. Read more here: [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

---

You have some other problems:

1. You are using bad variable names. Use better names than `cupcake` and `muffin`, ones that actually mean what the variable is. e.g. use `nextLine` instead of `cupcake` and `lineChars` instead of `muffin`.
2. You are attempting to parse empty lines. The simplest way to fix that is to add this loop to skip empty lines:

Code:

```
String cupcake = reader.nextLine();
while(cupcake.isEmpty()) cupcake = reader.nextLine();
```

3. You have `x` and `y` swapped in your loop. The way your loop works, `y` should be the first number and `x` should be the second number, e.g.

Code:

```
int y = reader.nextInt();
int x = reader.nextInt();
```

---

Here's my exact code:

#### gameOfLife/gameOfLife.java

```
package gameOfLife;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class gameOfLife {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File input = new File("gameBoardInput.txt");
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(input);
        int y = reader.nextInt();
        int x = reader.nextInt();

        Grid grid = new Grid(x, y);

        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            String cupcake = reader.nextLine();
            while (cupcake.isEmpty())
                cupcake = reader.nextLine();
            char[] muffin = cupcake.toCharArray();
            for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
                grid.setAt(i, j, muffin[j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### gameOfLife/Grid.java

```
package gameOfLife;

public class Grid {
    protected int[][] grid;

    public Grid(int x, int y) {
        grid = new int[x][y];
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
                grid[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    public int nuggets(int x, int y) {
        return grid[x][y];
    }

    public void setAt(int column, int row, int alive) {
        grid[column][row] = alive;
    }

}
```

#### gameBoardInput.txt

```
5
6
01000
00100
00010
01110
00100
00000
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I do apologize or the variable names, I promise I use better ones usually but I was very sick of looking at it last night so I vowed to change it later. 
I've added the while loop and changed the x's and y's around (whoops!) and re-compiled. After running it the same with java gameOfLife/GameOfLife I come up with the same error you are getting, still.

Comment: Oh I also removed the extra newlines from the input file. I edited your original post to match mine now. When I run it I get no error.

Comment: I tried it again with exactly what you edited, and I am still getting "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
        at gameOfLife.GameOfLife.main(GameOfLife.java:20)" I'm not sure why. All of the files are saved into the same folder and there are no extra files in it. I'm not sure what could be wrong still for it to give me that error.

Comment: @BriannaOrgeron I copy/pasted my entire code that is not giving me that error, maybe there's a mismatch somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Use a try-catch block in the main method, don't make it throw an exception.
What is your JDK version? Try something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    try{
        //insert code here
    }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
```

Also, use a `java.util.ArrayList<String>` to store the input text using its `add(<String>)` method. Then get the number of rows using size() and the number of columns using `get(0).length()`

Also, you have missing code. The main method does not have 20 lines and Exception occurs at line 20. It's probably due to a out-of-bounds condition in your code for calculating the neighbours, but we need the rest of the code to work that out. Please edit accordingly.